# Mirror production git repo in staging environment

Tags: git

We have a staging environment and a production environment.  We can do whatever we want in staging to test new continuous integration definitions/builds/releases etc...  Each environment has a git repo.

Currently, I have two local repos.  One for staging and one for production.  99% of the time we are working in production because it is not that often that we are changing build/release definitions.  However, we are currently making changes and I need to update the staging git repo code with the production code.

So, I basically just copy and paste the code from local production repo directory (minus any git related files) to the staging, then push to the staging the server.

This is lame, and I don't want to do this any more. So, what would be a more efficient set up?  Ideally, staging would just 'mirror' production, but we would not want changes made in staging to affect the production.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know whose idea it was to have two separate repos for staging and production, but I have not seen such a setup very often (or possibly even ever).  If you are versioning code for the same product in both repos, then the obvious fix here would be to just use a single repo for everything.  You would have staging and production branches in this single repo, and now if you needed to move features from staging to production or vice-versa, you would have things like merging and rebasing at your fingertips.

Comment: It is really more for the CI/Server configuration testing.  Update tfs versions, networking configurations...etc..so that Git configuration is only ever used when making changes that could impact other teams...so, this setup is not a part of our normal workflow.

Comment: @jparram I'm not familiar with the intricacies of your setup, but if you need to communicate information between two branches in the same repo in Git, it is relatively straightforward.  If you need to do the same between two branches in _different_ repos, it is apples to oranges, and you end up roughly where you are now, manually copying things or perhaps writing a script to do the same.

Comment: thank you for your time.  After the 2nd copy and paste, I scripted it...but was curious if there were other options when different repos are in the mix.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you said, you only need to create 1 repo with two main branches: `dev` and `master`. Whenever you want to use the code, for example as you said that :

> copy and paste the code from local production repo directory (minus any git related files) to the staging, then push to the staging the server.

Instead, checkout from branch `staging` to `staging-test` then `git pull --rebase origin master`, so the branch staging should be merged with `master` code.

You can take a look at GitFlow: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows

Answer (score 0):

You can add a git hook on git push to your local production repo which then switches to your local staging repo, pulls from your local production repo, and pushes to the remote staging repo.